# How to interpret the Lagrangian $\int d^3x \sqrt {-g} R$?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In GR, one of the degrees of freedom is that of the metric tensor. That means a tensor $g_{ab}$ at each point of space.

The other degree of freedom is that of the energy distribution. That's also a tensor field.

Then the Lagrangian should be something like:

$$L= \int \mathscr{L}(T, g) ~ d^4x$$

$\mathscr{L}(T,g)$ is the Lagrangian density. It's some scalar function of the energy distribution tensor, the metric tensor, and their first derivatives.

The actual Lagrangian has the Ricci scalar $R$. So there is a dependence on the metric. The $g$ is also just the determinant of the metric.

But where's the dependence on the matter-energy tensor $T$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Euler-Lagrange equations for the Einstein-Hilbert action $S_{\rm E.H.}=\frac{1}{16\pi G_N}\int d^4 x \sqrt{-g} R$ (in units where $c=1$ and where $G_N$ is Newton's constant) are Einstein's equations with no matter
\begin{equation}
G_{\mu\nu} = 0
\end{equation}
where $G_{\mu\nu}$ is the Einstein tensor.

To include matter, you need to add additional terms in the action containing matter fields, $S=S_{\rm E.H.} + S_{\rm matter}$. For instance, if you want to include the electromagnetic field, you would write an action
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{1}{16\pi G_N}\int d^4 x \sqrt{-g} R -\frac{1}{4} \int d^4 x \sqrt{-g} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
where $F_{\mu\nu}$ is the electromagnetic stress tensor. The Euler-Lagrange equations are
\begin{equation}
G_{\mu\nu} = 8 \pi G_N T^{\rm e.m.}_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
where $T^{\rm e.m.}_{\mu\nu}$ is the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor.

In general, writing
\begin{equation}
S = S_{\rm E.H.} + S_{\rm matter}
\end{equation}
and defining
\begin{equation}
T_{\mu\nu} = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S_{\rm matter}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}
\end{equation}
leads to Einstein's equations
\begin{equation}
G_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi G_N T_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}

Comment: Much thanks. There is no actual such thing as a free particle responding only to the spacetime curvature, right? Since every particle is composed of some other classical/quantum field, any particle must simultaneously respond to both spacetime curvature and their own field equations.

Comment: @EggMan All degrees of freedom (particle, field, ...) get their own equation of motion. So there is an equation of motion for the gravitational field (Einstein's equations), and an equation of motion for, say, a point particle. The equations are coupled, so the degrees of freedom *interact.* Thus, Einstein's equations depend on the stress-tensor of the point particle, and the point particle's equation of motion is the geodesic equation which depends on the metric tensor.

Comment: But a point particle responding only to the metric doesn't exist in reality, right? It only exists as an approximation. Because every particle is a field in quantum field theory.

Comment: @EggMan Yes, ideally to be exact we'd write down a fully quantum theory with all matter fields and gravity. Often this is overkill, though, so it's useful to look at point particles. Because we only know how to quantize gravity in an effective field theory sense, we always have to make some kind of approximation even when we do try to treat matter+gravity quantum mechanically (effective field theory of gravity, https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9512024).

Answer (score 1):

The energy momentum tensor is coupled to gravity via the volume element.
For example, for a free scalar field, the action will be

$$\int d^3x\sqrt{-g} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi$$

This is called minimal coupling, because matter is minimally coupled to gravity via the volume element $d^3x \sqrt{-g}$. One can also concider non-minimal couplings such as

$$\int d^3x\sqrt{-g} R \phi^2$$

or

$$\int d^3x\sqrt{-g}G^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\mu} \phi$$.

In these cases, matter is coupled stronger to gravity via these non-minimal couplings.

Comment: In addition to the determinant factor, there is also dependence on the metric via the inverse metric in your example, since $\partial^\mu \phi = g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu \phi$.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification!!!